# Action bar left icons not showing on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I use the following code to display a custom action bar:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.menu_example);
```

When testing with API 16, the icons, such as the drawer icon and up navigation icons, are not showing on the action bar (on the left). But when I remove my custom action bar, it works.
It works very well with newer APIs (such as APIs for 4.4, 5.0 ...).

Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed the problem using the following lines :

`getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.menu_example);
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);`